# Size grip is gone from status bar in Qt 5.1 on MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I'm porting a Qt application to Qt 5.1.1 from 4.8.5, and the sizegrip that used to be placed in the status bar on the right is gone on mac OS X. I checked the designer when creating the ui and it says that the grip is enabled. It is shown in the designer but the application when running does not display it.

I ran the same application on Windows, and there this issue is not present.

I am using Qt 5.1.1 on MacOSX 10.7.5. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading that it'd been disabled in newer releases to keep parity with OS X, as size grips don't appear in Cocoa anymore. I believe there is actually a compile time option to reenable it, or you can actually specify a `QSizeGrip` yourself which should bring it back.

Comment: You are right it has been removed. I can regain the functionality by using QSizeGrip *grip = statusBar()->findChild<QSizeGrip*>(); grip->setFixedSize(10,10); (or whatever size I like), and to reimplement the style, I use qproxystyle.